# How do I resolve the error "Attempt by security transparent method 'System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.get_Configuration()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have created a solution with two projects: A MVC 4 and a Class Library.  The solution compiles and runs fine.  I then install-package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData -pre to pull in OData WebApi functionality. When I do, I get the following error at runtime:

Attempt by security transparent method 'System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.get_Configuration()' to access security critical type 'System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration' failed.

When  WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration) runs in Global.asax

Once I do, uninstalling the package doesn't seem to fix.  It removes the OData components obviously, but then leaves whatever assembly is causing this.  removing with -RemoveDependencies removes ALL WebApi references in the library, and I'm unable to get it back in a working state.

What package hell am I in and how can I enable WebApi OData in a vanilla MVC4 app?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you create an MVC 4 app from its template, then you are installing Web API 4.0. if you use

```
install-package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData -pre
```

You will be dependent on ASP.NET Web API 5.0 rc.

My suggestion is to use "Empty ASP.NET web application" template rather than MVC 4.0 template.

Comment: This set me on the right track.  I ended up doing Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -Pre and it was happy.

Comment: Got the same error after installing `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` on VS2012 Web API template and editing the `WebApiConfig.Register`. After upgrading to VS2013 template all worked properly.

Answer (score 35):

It's a mismatch on the assemblies for the given version of WebAPI. Mine was failing because I was referencing a mismatched version of `System.Web.Http.WebHost`. So you can...

1. Install the latest WebAPI from NuGet

   -OR-
2. Make sure all your `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.*` packages are on the same version

Answer (score 16):

I ran "update-package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" in the Package Manager Console in VS and worked like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing same issue and fix is to use same version of "System.Web.Http.WebHost" as Syste.Web.Http which is 5.2.6

Answer (score 3):

Do you need the pre-release version of web API OData? If so, you need to update all the other web API packages to match that version. 
If not, just do,

```
install-package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData
```

without the `-pre` option

Answer (score 2):

If this package don't exist from the answers above you can install it

install-package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi

Answer (score 0):

I faced issue and I noticed, previous server code build with Release mode and I am uploading build with Debug mode code.
So, I replaced with Release mode and then issue is resolved.